# How to make a div draggable inside a shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

I am using customElements in a django project in order to make reusable components. In each of these it seems necessary to use a shadow-tree which I have been doing with relative ease

However I really need a particular div inside a shadow-dom to be draggable (not in the CSS sense - actually movable). I explored a few options, particularly `interactjs` and `jqueryUI`. However NOTHING i can find works within the shadow-dom.

Is there really no way to make a draggable element if its inside a shadow DOM?

Comment: of course you can

Comment: @Supersharp Using what library? I cannot select elements with JQuery in shadow dom so no JQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in vanilla Javascript:

Use a `draggable` element in the Shadow DOM and process the `dragstart`, `dragover`, and `drop` event as explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

```js
customElements.define( 'drag-div', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        let sh = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        sh.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                :host { 
                    display: block ;
                    height: 50px ;
                    border: 1px solid red ;
                }
                [draggable] {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin : 20px ;
                    cursor: pointer ;
                    background-color: lightblue ;
                }
            </style>
            <div draggable=true>drag me</div>`
        sh.querySelector( '[draggable]' )
          .ondragstart = ev => ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.outerHTML )
    }
} )

customElements.define( 'drop-div', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        let sh = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        sh.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                    :host { 
                        display: block ;
                        height: 50px ;
                        border: 1px solid green ;
                    }
                    :host>div {
                        height: 100% ;
                    }
            </style>
            <div></div>`
        let div = sh.querySelector( 'div' )
        div.ondragover = ev => ev.preventDefault()
        div.ondrop = ev => div.innerHTML += ev.dataTransfer.getData( 'text/html' )         
    }
} )
```

```html
<drag-div></drag-div>
<drop-div></drop-div>
```

Comment: Note, this is the native HTML5 Drag-Drop API which does not work on touch devices. For touch you need to do some extra work: https://www.horuskol.net/blog/2020-08-15/drag-and-drop-elements-on-touch-devices/